# http.get request jumps the function(result)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find why does my function jumps after the request is done..
I mean it doesn't enter on `.then(function(result){ }`.

I think it might be because of the `<a>` element that has an `onclick` attribute with an `href` attribute.

Have you ever seen this problem?

```
var app = angular.module('devicesFromGroup', ['ngResource']);

var myInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
var $http = myInjector.get("$http");
//var $scope= myInjector.get("$scope");

function funcb($http){
    console.log("OLIEIEIEIEI");
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/stuff/2')
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("it's not printed");
    });
}

function funcC(id){
    myInjector.invoke(funcb);
    return true;
};
```

And then, in other JavaScript I have:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href',"http://localhost:8080/DevicesFromGroup.html");
a.setAttribute('onclick',"funcC(id);");
```

Comment: How are you calling it? You mentioned href, if you're using an anchor tag you may need to prevent the default action of the link

Comment: Did you try to add an error callback? I assume your webservice does not return HTTP 200, so your success callback is never called. Check this out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: My goal is to click on a <a> element and it executes that function on a new html (href i mentioned)... yea i think you are right sterling archer.. how can i solve it? The webservice is returning http200

Comment: FYI : [tag:angular] tag is for angular 2+, [tag:angularjs] tag is for angular 1.x. @PJMC

Comment: Do you think thats the reason why its not working? @n00dl3

Comment: Try removing $http from the function definition. $http inside function is a parameter of the function

Comment: didnt work @Vivz :s

Comment: Can u post the full controller code ?

Comment: @PJMC Please, [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Also note that putting wrong tags will just make the task harder for people willing to help.

Comment: Wrong tags? I put javascript and angular... whats wrong here ? lol

Comment: @Vivz here you have

Comment: javascript doesn't persist between page loads. Can't execute code in one page on another

Comment: So theres no way to open the html in a new page? @charlietfl

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: basicly i want to click on a button and open a different page with some data that is returned by an webservice.. the thing is.. i need some data to make the call that is on the old js related to the old html... got it? thats why i'm trying to call a function that the ng app and controller are in the page that i put in href.. I hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

there is a possibility that the call returns an error . then block is invoked for success only. See below i have added a catch block for displaying in console in case of error.

```
function funcb($http){
        console.log("OLIEIEIEIEI");
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/stuff/2')
        .then(function(result) {

            console.log("it's not printed");


        })  
       .catch(function (err) {
          console.log("There was an error: "+err);
       });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it's not the case.. it returns http 200